# Debugging a jax-ws client in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws, soap-client

I am writing a java client for a web service. I used wsimport to generate the proxies. Copied them over to my workspace project (in eclipse). Wrote a simple program using couple of ws calls. Now when I want to step into a soap call, eclipse says that source code for the file was not found (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.class). It's using this class from rt.jar which is pointing to the src.zip that came with the installation. I noticed that src.zip does not contain the missing java files, so I downloaded them separately and tried adding them to zip file. I also tried copying them over to my project to see if I can trick eclipse into accepting them as the source file.

I don't write/debug Java on a regular basis so please help me out here. I really want to debug and see what jax-ws is doing differently from axis as the call works in the later implementation.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that you can set the following System property to put JAX-WS in debug mode.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

See [JAX-WS Guide - Logging](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Logging.html).

Comment: I think the link is outdated. Perhaps the most recent is this one https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#logging